# How is this JS timer being paused?

Tags: javascript, timer

http://jsbin.com/hafejebaho/edit?html,output

Hi all.  I found this timer code and it functions quite nicely.  I am trying to understand the logic of it, and I can't seem to figure out how the timer is being paused when i press the startPause button.

according to the code, when you press startPause when running == 0 then the increment() starts.  however, when you press the startPause again when running ==1 then there is no function that actually stops the timer.  how is that possible. I see that the running is set to 0 and the button name changes to "resume" but there is no other function to actually stop the timer..   I would have thought that they must be some kind of break timer function.

its a noob question but i would appreciate any answers...  tx..

Comment: if you click startPause and the timer is running it set `running` variable to `0`  and if running is different then 1 the `increment` function will not call itself after timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of the `increment()` function:

```
function increment() {
    if (running == 1) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            time++;
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = time;
            increment();
        }, 100);
     }
}
```

Specifically, the logic inside the `increment()` function will only run if `running == 1`. Since `running == 0` when you press pause, the logic stops there.